# Duplicate text on a line and insert things around it with Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following text on lines in a text file.

```
34233-XR43-2343
34234-GH33-3434
23567-RF32-5266
234552667
09223-23RF-5237
```

I want to tab and duplicate that text and place it in the same line with additional text at the beginning and end.

For example: (Consider white space to be a tab)

```
34233-XR43-2343    ~/images/products/34233-XR43-2343.jpg
34234-GH33-3434    ~/images/products/34234-GH33-3434.jpg
23567-RF32-5266    ~/images/products/23567-RF32-5266.jpg
234552667          ~/images/products/234552667.jpg
09223-23RF-5237    ~/images/products/09223-23RF-5237.jpg
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here should __show research effort or attempts__. Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your format, you can use the following regular expression to do this.

```
Find: ^(\S+)
Replace: \1\t~/images/products/\1.jpg
```

**Explanation**:

```
^          # the beginning of the string
(          # group and capture to \1:
  \S+      #   non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
)          # end of \1
```

In the replacement, we use `\1` to reference what was matched and captured by capturing group `#1`.

Comment: You're welcome, next time please post an attempt of what you have tried so you get more feedback and less downvotes on SO

Comment: Understood! I'm new to regex but really want to learn. Any good tutorials you can point me to?